Node Guardian - run Start Adventure gives NPM dependency error
I am trying to setup Node Guardians. Prerequisites on Tutorial says Node version 18 or later. When run "npm run start adventure", I get a series of "Conflicting Peer Dependency" and/or "Could not Resolve Upstream Dependency" errors.
I downloaded npm and nvm versions for windows 11. On picture is seen the node version is v18.20.4. I have tried to search for answers and havent found a reference to help me solve the errors. https://nodeguardians.io/adventure/setting-up/part-2.[npm error node guardian setup](https://i.sstatic.net/ExF61lZP.png).
